# How to solve the equation with complexity O(n^2)?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

$S,T \in \Bbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and both are nonsingular upper triangle matrix. Give an algorithm with $O(n^2)$ to solve the nonsingular equation $(ST-{\lambda}I)x = b$

Comment: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/ResearchPDF/ProdTri.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's been a great help!!!